# How to handle the error of enabling telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I have a telegram bot, but over time or immediately upon startup it gets a connection error. To write a bot, I use the "telebot" library.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bottoken/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02FB6910>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))
```

How to handle this error and try to turn on the bot until it turns on?

Comment: `try/except` and catch this specific exception in the except block you can start your bot

Comment: Should it be?
```res_connect=False
while res_connect!=True:
    try:
        res_connect=False
        bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    except Exception as err:
        res_connect=False ```

Comment: I am not sure how the telegram bot works, but don't think you'd need the while as long as the connection is opened. However, check the answer below for the try catch suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - use `ConnectionError` from `requests.eceptions`

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
   Bot working and doing stuff
except ConnectionError as e:
   log e
   start Bot()
```